# AllenNLP Multi-Task Model: Keep encoder weights for new heads

Tags: pytorch, allennlp

I have trained a (AllenNLP) multi-task model. I would like to keep the encoder/backbone weights and continue training with new heads on new datasets. How can I do that with AllenNLP?

I have two basic ideas for how to do that:

1. I followed [this AllenNLP tutorial](https://guide.allennlp.org/building-your-model#3) to load the trained model and then instead of just making predictions I wanted to change the configuration and the model-heads to continue training on the new datasets...but I am kinda lost in how to do that.
2. I guess it should be possible to (a) save the state-dict of the previously trained encoder in a file and then (b) point to those weights in the configuration file for the new model (instead of pointing to "bert-base-cased"-weights for example). But looking at the [PretrainedTransformerEmbedder-class](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/allennlp/modules/token_embedders/pretrained_transformer_embedder.py) I don't see how I could pass my own model-weights to that class.

As an additional question: Is it also possible to save the weights of the heads separately and initialize new heads with those weights?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second idea is the preferred way, which you can accomplish by using a [`PretrainedModelInitializer`](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/542ce5d9137840e8197ef5781cd12f02f1c86f79/allennlp/nn/initializers.py#L325). See the [`CopyNet`](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/6b306b004deffc866ee28404b2fe2ee0d93530ca/allennlp_models/generation/models/copynet_seq2seq.py#L149) model for an example of how to add this to your model.